# Object required Error when error handling

Tags: vba, web-scraping, error-handling

The following code retrieves 'dossier Urls' for substances in Column A by scraping the ECHA website. I'm trying to error handle cases where a substance Url cannot be found.

I can't quite see why the following code fails. I have highlighted the Problematic line with a comment. this is highlighted in debugging as an Object Required error but I can't see where I'm going wrong.

```
Sub PopulateExposures()
    Dim url, rw As Range
    
    Set rw = Sheets("data").Range("A2:E2") 'first row with inputs
    Do While Application.CountA(rw) > 0
        url = SubstanceUrl(rw.Cells(1).Value, rw.Cells(2).Value) 'get the URL
        rw.Cells(5).Resize(1, 3).Value = ExposureData(url) 'get exposure data (as array) and add to row
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0) 'next substance
    Loop

End Sub

Public Function SubstanceUrl(SubstanceName, CASNumber) As String
    
    Const url = "https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/registered-substances?" & _
                "p_p_id=dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&" & _
                "p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&" & _
                "__dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_javax.portlet.action=dissRegisteredSubstancesAction"
    
    Dim oHTML, oHttp, MyDict, payload, DictKey, sep
    
    Set oHTML = New HTMLDocument
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    MyDict("_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_name") = SubstanceName
    MyDict("_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_cas-number") = CASNumber
    MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimer") = "true"
    MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimerCheckbox") = "on"
    
    payload = ""
    For Each DictKey In MyDict
        payload = payload & sep & DictKey & "=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(MyDict(DictKey))
        sep = "&"
    Next DictKey
        
    With oHttp
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send payload
        oHTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    'PROBLEMATIC CODE
    If oHTML.querySelector(".details").getAttribute("href") Is Error Then
    
    SubstanceUrl = "-"
    Else
    
     'Sometimes output changes despite same input
    SubstanceUrl = oHTML.querySelector(".details").getAttribute("href")
    
    End If
    
    
    Debug.Print SubstanceUrl
    
    
    
End Function

Function ExposureData(urlToGet)
    
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument, dds
    Dim Route(1 To 3) As String, Results(1 To 3) As String, c, Info, Data
    
    Route(1) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaInhalationRoute"
    Route(2) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaDermalRoute"
    Route(3) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaOralRoute"
    
    XMLReq.Open "Get", urlToGet & "/7/1", False
    XMLReq.send
     
    If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        Results(1) = "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
    Else
        Set HTMLDoc = New HTMLDocument
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
        For c = 1 To UBound(Route, 1)
            Set Info = HTMLDoc.getElementById(Route(c))
            If Not Info Is Nothing Then
                Set Info = Info.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling
                Set dds = Info.getElementsByTagName("dd")
                If dds.Length > 1 Then
                    Results(c) = dds(1).innerText
                Else
                    Results(c) = "hazard unknown"
                End If
            Else
                Results(c) = "no info"
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    
    ExposureData = Results
    
End Function
```

For this code to run values must be present in column A. Acetone and Benzene can be used respectively to test 2 rows.  To test out the error handling Enter something made up like Benzenjaj.

I think this is a quick fix. Just can't see it.

Update:

Tetsing on made up substance name:
[image]

First 2 results are found as normal but the made-up chemical causes the following error:

[image]
[image]

- **Code:**

  Sub PopulateExposures()
  Dim url, rw As Range

  ```
   Set rw = Sheets("data").Range("A2:E2") 'first row with inputs
   Do While Application.CountA(rw) > 0
       url = SubstanceUrl(rw.Cells(1).Value, rw.Cells(2).Value) 'get the URL
       rw.Cells(5).Resize(1, 3).Value = ExposureData(url) 'get exposure data (as array) and add to row
       Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0) 'next substance
   Loop
  ```

  End Sub

  Public Function SubstanceUrl(SubstanceName, CASNumber) As String

  ```
   Const url = "https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/registered-substances?" & _
               "p_p_id=dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&" & _
               "p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&" & _
               "__dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_javax.portlet.action=dissRegisteredSubstancesAction"

   Dim oHTML, oHttp, MyDict, payload, DictKey, sep

   Set oHTML = New HTMLDocument
   Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
   Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

   MyDict("_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_name") = SubstanceName
   MyDict("_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_cas-number") = CASNumber
   MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimer") = "true"
   MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimerCheckbox") = "on"

   payload = ""
   For Each DictKey In MyDict
       payload = payload & sep & DictKey & "=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(MyDict(DictKey))
       sep = "&"
   Next DictKey

   With oHttp
       .Open "POST", url, False
       .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
       .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
       .send payload
       oHTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
   End With

   On Error Resume Next 'ignore error on following line
   SubstanceUrl = oHTML.querySelector(".details").getAttribute("href")
   On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors

   If Len(SubstanceUrl) = 0 Then SubstanceUrl = "<no URL>"
  ```

  End Function

  Function ExposureData(urlToGet)

  ```
   Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
   Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument, dds
   Dim Route(1 To 3) As String, Results(1 To 3) As String, c, Info, Data

   Route(1) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaInhalationRoute"
   Route(2) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaDermalRoute"
   Route(3) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaOralRoute"

   XMLReq.Open "Get", urlToGet & "/7/1", False
   XMLReq.send

   If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
       Results(1) = "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
   Else
       Set HTMLDoc = New HTMLDocument
       HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
       For c = 1 To UBound(Route, 1)
           Set Info = HTMLDoc.getElementById(Route(c))
           If Not Info Is Nothing Then
               Set Info = Info.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling
               Set dds = Info.getElementsByTagName("dd")
               If dds.Length > 1 Then
                   Results(c) = dds(1).innerText
               Else
                   Results(c) = "hazard unknown"
               End If
           Else
               Results(c) = "no info"
           End If
       Next c
   End If

   ExposureData = Results
  ```

  End Function

Comment: The `Is` operator compares 2 objects.  The getAttribute method returns a String which is not an Object.

Comment: How can I set the output of this string to an object to check if the URL exists or not?

Comment: @BrianMStafford I dont understand how `Info` in the bottom module is a string but the `Is` operator appears to work?

Comment: `Info` is not a String.  It is a Variant containing an Object as evidenced by the line `Set Info =`.  You only need the Set keyword for Objects.  Also, it would be better to define Info as the proper type.  Something like `Dim Info As IHTMLElement`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just ignore any error:

```vb
    With oHttp
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send payload
        oHTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error on following line
    SubstanceUrl = oHTML.querySelector(".details").getAttribute("href")
    On Error Goto 0      'stop ignoring errors

    If Len(SubstanceUrl) = 0 Then SubstanceUrl = "<no URL>"
```

Comment: Hi Tim, this appears to fail if I use a made up substance

Comment: Also I would like the cells where a URL isn't found to actually return some character like "-"

Comment: "Fail" means what exactly?  What does that look like?  If the `querySelector()` fails then it should return "<no URL>"

Comment: Please See the update to the question to see images of the problem and the code I have used from your answer.

Comment: Before passing the URL to `ExposureData` you need to check it's not equal to "<no URL>"

Answer (score 1):

You can test the .Length of querySelectorAll when looking for the particular registered dossier url. You need to amend your code elsewhere to handle the "-" return url. I prefer Tim's solution in terms of ignoring error however for the first bit.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PopulateExposures()
    Dim url, rw As Range
    
    Set rw = Sheets("data").Range("A2:E2")       'first row with inputs
    Do While Application.CountA(rw) > 0
        url = SubstanceUrl(rw.Cells(1).Value, rw.Cells(2).Value) 'get the URL
        If Left$(url, 5) = "https" Then
            rw.Cells(5).Resize(1, 3).Value = ExposureData(url) 'get exposure data (as array) and add to row
        Else
            rw.Cells(5).Resize(1, 3).Value = url
        End If
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0)                 'next substance
    Loop

End Sub

Public Function SubstanceUrl(SubstanceName, CASNumber) As String
    
    Const url = "https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/registered-substances?" & _
    "p_p_id=dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&" & _
    "p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&" & _
    "__dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_javax.portlet.action=dissRegisteredSubstancesAction"
    
    Dim oHTML, oHttp, MyDict, payload, DictKey, sep
    
    Set oHTML = New HTMLDocument
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    MyDict("_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_name") = SubstanceName
    MyDict("_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_cas-number") = CASNumber
    MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimer") = "true"
    MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimerCheckbox") = "on"
    
    payload = ""
    For Each DictKey In MyDict
        payload = payload & sep & DictKey & "=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(MyDict(DictKey))
        sep = "&"
    Next DictKey
        
    With oHttp
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send payload
        oHTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    If oHTML.querySelectorAll("[href*=registered-dossier]").Length = 0 Then
    
        SubstanceUrl = "-"
        
    Else
    
        'Sometimes output changes despite same input
        SubstanceUrl = oHTML.querySelector(".details")
    
    End If
    
    
    Debug.Print SubstanceUrl
      
End Function

Function ExposureData(urlToGet)
    
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument, dds
    Dim Route(1 To 3) As String, Results(1 To 3) As String, c, Info, Data
    
    Route(1) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaInhalationRoute"
    Route(2) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaDermalRoute"
    Route(3) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaOralRoute"
    
    XMLReq.Open "Get", urlToGet & "/7/1", False
    XMLReq.send
     
    If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        Results(1) = "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
    Else
        Set HTMLDoc = New HTMLDocument
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
        For c = 1 To UBound(Route, 1)
            Set Info = HTMLDoc.getElementById(Route(c))
            If Not Info Is Nothing Then
                Set Info = Info.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling
                Set dds = Info.getElementsByTagName("dd")
                If dds.Length > 1 Then
                    Results(c) = dds(1).innerText
                Else
                    Results(c) = "hazard unknown"
                End If
            Else
                Results(c) = "no info"
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    
    ExposureData = Results
    
End Function
```